# How to navigate to another activity from activity launched from Notification Without Overriding OnBackPressed()?

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-manifest

I have 3 activities suppose MainActivity, FirstActivity, NotificationActivity and when user clicks on a notification from my app activity C will be launched, what I want is the user to be able to go back to B on pressing back button, I want to achieve this without overriding the OnBackPressed() method on doing some R&D i found a method of using the manifest to specify the parent activity to go back to another activity, its working from B->A and C->A but I cant figure how to get C->B working. I'll post the manifest file which I am working on. If needed I'll post the class files if needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.notificationmultipledemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_first"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NotificationActivity" 
        android:label="@string/title_activity_notification" 
        android:parentActivityName=".FirstActivity">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" 
            android:value=".FirstActivity" />
    </activity>


</application>
```

Here is the Class A which is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
   private NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
   private int notificationIdOne = 111;
   private int notificationIdTwo = 112;
   private int numMessagesOne = 0;
   private int numMessagesTwo = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button notOneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notificationOne);
      notOneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            displayNotificationOne();
         }
      });

      Button notTwoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notificationTwo);
      notTwoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            displayNotificationTwo();
         }
      });

   }

   protected void displayNotificationOne() {

      // Invoking the default notification service
      NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);  

      mBuilder.setContentTitle("New Message with explicit intent");
      mBuilder.setContentText("New message from Cheers received");
      mBuilder.setTicker("Explicit: New Message Received!");
      mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

      // Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives 
      mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessagesOne);

      // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app 
      Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
      //resultIntent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationIdOne);
   // when the user presses the notification, it is auto-removed
      mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
      //This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of the app to Home page
      TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
      // Adds the back stack for the Intent
      stackBuilder.addParentStack(FirstActivity.class);

      // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
      stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
      PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
         stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT 
         );
      // start the activity when the user clicks the notification text
      mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

      myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      Date now = new Date();
        long uniqueId = now.getTime();//use date to generate an unique id to differentiate the notifications.
      // pass the Notification object to the system
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat_notification = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String Notificationdate = simpledateformat_notification.format(c.getTime());
        String[] Notification_time = Notificationdate.split(":");
        //int Beacon_hour = Integer.parseInt(Notification_time[0]); //7
        int Notification_minutes =Integer.parseInt(Notification_time[2]);

      myNotificationManager.notify(Notification_minutes, mBuilder.build());
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the displayNotificationOne() replace

```
stackBuilder.addParentStack(FirstActivity.class);
```

with

```
stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
```

if you want the user to navigate from NotificationActivity to FirstActivity when the back button is pressed, also you will be able to go from FirstActivity to the MainActivity here becuase of the manifest. If you don't want that to happen then remove the meta data and parentActivityName in the activity section of FirstActivity.